# Crispy Forms: Default selected value for FieldSet

Tags: django-crispy-forms

I have a list of items that I'm populating into a crispy forms ChoiceField

For the life of me, I can't figure out how to set which item in REGION_CHOICE is selected by default.

```
    REGIONS = {
       'us': 'US VALUE',
       'ch': 'CH VALUE'
    }

    REGION_CHOICE = list(REGIONS.items())
    region = forms.ChoiceField(label='', choices=REGION_CHOICE, required=True)
```

Layout:

```
    self.helper.layout = Layout(
        Field('request', placeholder='Begin with a value...'),
        Field('region'),
        Submit("SUBMIT", "SUBMIT"),
        HTML('<a href="{% url \'rush\' %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-md right">rush History</a>')
    )
```

How can I select a default value for my  input?

Answer (score 0):

You need a *default* parameter in field attributes, where You put a value. Sample:

```
region = forms.ChoiceField(default='us')
```